# Facebook Graph API doesn't return feed on some pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot get posts feed from this public page (id is 262011690578021):
https://www.facebook.com/pages/PUMA-Social-Club-Gorky-Park/262011690578021?__mref=message_bubble

Here is check that api doesn't return any data on connection "feed" or "posts"
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=262011690578021%3Ffields%3Dposts&version=v2.5

But other pages are OK!
What's wrong with this particular page?

Comment: are you using an app or page token? the page may be restricted by age or location.

Comment: Are you sure there are posts made by that page? the /posts edge returns items posted by that page - everything i see on the timeline was made by another user or page, tagged as being at 145634995501895

Comment: @lgy yes, i think you are right - posts on this page with caption "Publications about PUMA Social Club Gorky Park"? but not this page. Do you know how to capture that posts?

Comment: You need to use a user token for a user that is able to see those posts. (Or a page token; but that you can only get if you have admin access to the page.)